# Center a formatted row of integers in Python?

Tags: python

I am a bit new to Python, having dabbled in VB.NET, C, and a few other odd languages, so I am finding the approaches used before don't always apply to Python.  In this case, I want to print out a series of integer values into columns and center them in as small amount of code as possible.

With plain strings, this is easy as:

```
print "%s|%s|%s|%s"   \
      % (s1.center(w), s2.center(x), s3.center(y), s4.center(z))
```

Where `w` through `z` is some integer value specifying the width of the field that the strings, `s1` through `s4`, should be center in.

Doing the same with numbers when I want to use format specifiers like `%0.2x` or `%4d` won't work because integers don't have a `center` function.

Using a more C-oriented approach, I could convert each integer independently:

```
s1 = str("%0.4x" % (i)).center(w)
s2 = str("%0.2x" % (i)).center(x)
s3 = str("%0.2x" % (i)).center(y)
s4 = str("%0.8x" % (i)).center(z)
print "%s|%s|%s|%s" % (s1, s2, s3, s4)
```

But that seems to be "unpythonic", if I am picking up the lingo correctly.  What would be a good "pythonic" way to do this?  It needs to be something that works with Python 2.4 and 2.7 (I am working in both environments).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ints = [1, 2, 3, 4]
widths = [(4, w), (2, x), (2, y), (8, z)]
for i in ints:
    print "%s|%s|%s|%s" % tuple(((("%0." + str(padding) + "d") % (i)).center(width)) for padding, width in widths)
```

Each tuple in `widths` is (padding, width), where each padding associated with a width is used in the string formatting `"%0.[padding]d"`.

Comment: This addresses my need, though I'll try to find a way to optimize out the double for loops.  Python seems to have some curious knacks for doing things not available in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can emphasize the fact that each value is being formatted the same way:

```
def as_output_field(value, width):
    return ('%0.4d' % value).center(width)
```

And you can handle the widths and values in a data-driven way:

```
values = [s1,s2,s3,s4]
widths = [w,x,y,z]
```

And you can emphasize the fact that your format consists of a bunch of similar fields separated by a common character:

```
print '|'.join(as_output_field(value, width) for value, width in zip(values, widths))
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer.  It doesn't fully answer my specific example, though, because my output will be in hex and with different padding amounts.  Which I probably should have stated from the get-go.  BUT, it does provide a solution to another function I have in the same script.  You get an upvote for that, at least.  But I have to go with U-DON's example as the more complete solution, though I will most likely fiddle with both and maybe merge them or evolve some hybrid of the two.  Pity I can't split my answer half and half.

Comment: The 'different padding amounts' can be handled with another list in the same manner. Or you could make a class to bind a number together with its intended formatting. Hexification is also trivial to insert in the process.